# Haskell Complex Function Types

Tags: function, haskell, types

A Haskell function I am struggling with has the following type

`func1 :: (Integer -> Integer -> Integer) -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer`

I am unsure of how to handle the Parenthesis piece in the actual implementation. I know that a function should be passed into the input in this scenario.
`(Integer -> Integer -> Integer)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a function is passed to you as a parameter, the only useful thing you can do with it in the end is to *call* it. That's what functions are for. That's what they do.

For example, in this case it may look something like this:

```
func1 :: (Integer -> Integer -> Integer) -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
func1 f a b = f (a*2) (b+5)
```

Here, the first parameter is named `f` and it's a function that takes two parameters, both `Integer`, and returns another `Integer` - that much is conveyed by its type `(Integer -> Integer -> Integer)`.

The second and third parameters are named `a` and `b` respectively, and they're both `Integer`.

The body of function `func1` consists of calling its function-parameter `f`, passing it `(a*2)` and `(b+5)` as parameters.

Comment: In fact, the *simplest* thing you can do is just call the function on the given arguments: `func1 f a b = f a b`. With a little thought, you should be able to convince yourself that `func1 = id`.